# Insert Formula into cell using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to insert a formula into a cell using vba. This formula will need to have references to activecell.row range or dynamic reference.

I am using the following vba code:

```
Range("P" & ActiveCell.Row).Formula = "=IF(OR(G & ActiveCell.Row <>"",""H"" & ActiveCell.Row <>"",""I"" & ActiveCell.Row <>"",""J"" & ActiveCell.Row <>"",""M"" & ActiveCell.Row <>""),TODAY(),"")"
```

I get an Application defined or object defined error. Please can someone show me where i am going wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

assuming that what you want is this formula:

```
=IF(OR(G1<>"",H1<>"",I1<>"",J1<>"",M1<>""),TODAY(),"")
```

Try this

```
Range("P" & ActiveCell.Row).Formula = "=IF(OR(G" & ActiveCell.Row & "<>"""",H" & ActiveCell.Row & "<>"""",I" & ActiveCell.Row & "<>"""",J" & ActiveCell.Row & "<>"""",M" & ActiveCell.Row & "<>""""),TODAY(),"""")"
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `R1C1` notation and `CountA()` to simplify a bit

```
Range("P" & ActiveCell.row).FormulaR1C1 = "=if(counta(RC7:RC10,RC13)>0,Today(),"""")"
```

Comment: @M.Doe, did you get through it?

Comment: @M.Doe, it'd be nice of you giving proper feedbacks to people trying at helping you. thank you

Answer (score -1):

I think the issue is with the double-quotes. You have:

```
...).Formula = "=IF(OR(G & ActiveCell.Row <>"",""H"" & ActiveCell..."
```

While it should be:

```
...).Formula = "=IF(OR(G & ActiveCell.Row <>"""",""""H"""" & ActiveCell..."
```

Remember: In a string enclosed within -"- chars, any appearance of the same char within the string must be doubled.

Didn't check this though, but I quite sure this is an error (perhaps not THE error).

Comment: thanks i tried this suggestion but still get the same error.